# What is wrong with object (stage) sizes AIR 3.4 FOR IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, air, flash-builder

if you trace stage.stageHeight you will get 370 instead of 960

stageFullscreenHeight will return 960

in one of my projects there is such a bug but later in code it seems that stage FIXES ITSELF

this is for flash builder 4.7 beta 2

on device on simulator on debug via simulator this screws up all positioning

also things like stage align produce weird results.

Answer (score 0):

To fix that: add enterframe event listener in your class function - then remove it (you can put a trace before and after on stage width) after it runs 1 time - then execute all positioning stuff and VOILA - all back to 960 or whatever you define.

Hope this helps some1

Cheers!